# Write a C program to create a unnamed pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, parent-child

Write a C program which is used to create unnamed pipe. Parent process creates a new child process and both the processes will communicate with each other.

Solution that I have tried.

Is this the right way to make use of unnamed pipe?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<unistd.h>
 #include<string.h>
 
 int main() {
     int fd[2] , ret = 0;
     char buffer[] = "Marvellous InfoSystems";
     char readBuff[BUFSIZ];
     pid_t Childpid;
 
     pipe(fd);                                           //create a oneway communication channel i.e pipe i.e unnamed pipe
 
     Childpid = fork();
 
     if(Childpid == 0)                                   //child process
     {
         close(fd[0]);                                   /*close the ipnut side of the pipe after entering the child process*/
         printf("Child intiaites communication by writing the data at output side of the pipe \n");
         write(fd[1] , buffer , sizeof(buffer));         /*Child process writes at the output side of the pipe*/
     }
     else                                                //parent process
     {
         close(fd[1]);                                   /*Close output side of the pipe after the entering the parent proces*/
         ret = read(fd[0] , readBuff , sizeof(readBuff));/*Parent proces reads the data i.e written by the child at output side of the
 pipe*/
         printf("The data read by Parent process is : %s \n",readBuff);
     }
 
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) The return form fork can be -1 on failure. You should check for that first. 2) you trust the recieved data to be nul-terminated. It is not.

Comment: There are too many stray `>`s to produce compilation error :(

Comment: @MikeCAT ... I removed those.

Comment: @wildplasser The sent data is null-terminated. The received data will be null-terminated assuming that `BUFSIZ` is not less than the size of data sent.

Comment: @MikeCAT readbuff is not initialised.

Comment: @wildplasser I added initialization of `readbuff` with some string. If the reading don't null-terminate the buffer, the numbers will appear on output. Actually they don't and it is suggesting that the reading will do null-termination. https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZbLg1oVJFvNmHSM7

Comment: Adding `#include <sys/types.h>` will increase the chance for this code to be compiled.

Comment: The code seems to be working correctly when I test it.  If you want suggestions for improvements to working code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com may be the better site.

Comment: As a first draft, it is working (proof of concept). But now, you should add the check of the values returned by the system calls (pipe(), fork(), read(), write() may fail). You can also add a wait() on the child termination in the father's branch.